# Un-ignore sub dir doesn't show untracked files

Tags: git

I have following in .gitignore:

```
wordpress/*
!wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/
!wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/*
```

But when I do `git status` it's not seeing the untracked files.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format): *It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.*

Comment: Is there any way to include the sub dir without the parent dir?

Comment: No. You need to include all intermediate directories in path.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format), I believe you want something like

```
!/wordpress
/wordpress/*
!/wordpress/..../
```

However, my preferred solution is to *add* files I want to tracked. I would do in ignore (either `.git/info/exclude` for just you or `.gitignore` for everyone):

```
/wordpress/*
```

And then run

```
git add -N path/to/files/to/track
```